# How to write `Aggregate` in `from .. in ..` notation?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to write

```
string result = strings.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (s, a) => s.AppendLine(a)).ToString();
```

in `from a in strings select ...` form?

Comment: I don't believe you can.

Comment: Maybe I can emulate it using some other keywords?

Comment: See my answer for other keywords.

Comment: You could, but you would need to do it in VB instead of C# since VB supports the Aggregate, Sum, Count keywords as native query keywords.

Comment: @Jim: What would the OP's solution look like in VB with the `Aggregate` keyword?

Comment: Actually, I wrote that before realizing that they were using the Aggregate extension method. To do Count/Sum in VB you could write dim result = Aggregate s In strings Into Count(s). Aggregate() does require the Lambda syntax in VB as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. See here for a list of LINQ query keywords:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx

However you do it you'd still need to call a method (`Aggrigate`).

Answer (score 1):

How about a solution without the need for Aggregate at all:

```
    string[] strings = {"1", "2", "3"};
    string result = String.Join("\r", strings);
```

Comment: +1; I'd recommend this in most cases as it is much easier to tell what is going on.  Linq is priceless, but sometimes your problem is less abstract.  This also doesn't append a newline at the end (which often is preferable).

Comment: Actually I have much more complex query, and there are dictionaries instead of strings.